# Default margins, indent, font size for \documentclass{article}

Tags: formatting, article

I am trying to find the default top, bottom, left, right page margins for \documentclass{article} along with the top, bottom, indent for title, section, subsection, etc. I am looking also of section/sub-subsections text size along with respective margins and paragraph indent. I want to replicate these in a MS Word file as I would like to standardise every document I have. Paper size: A4, default text size 11pt.

Thank you in advance,

Best regards,

A.

Comment: See the geometry package, AFAIR it has a feature where it does not change the current layout, just prints out the margin settings to the log. As for the standard font sizes they are listed in size11.clo for 11pt. Remember that LaTeX uses tex points, I'm not sure what  MS Word uses for the size of 1pt

Comment: @daleif Thank you for this, however I have no clue how I could do that. Any help? Thank you in advance. Sizes are easy to convert, nothing to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

See the `geometry` manual for what `pass` and `verbose` does.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pass,verbose]{geometry}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Then the default settings are listed in the log and terminal.

All the font sizes used by `11pt` for the `article` class are listed in `size11.clo`, find it on your system.

Comment: Dear @daleif, thank you for this! Although the log provides me the information I need with reference to the page margins, I cannot find any information related to the default top/bottom margins of the geometry package in the case of sections, subsections, subsubsections etc. Any ideas? Thank you once more!

Comment: @meletkis then you will have to look inside `article.cls` and learn what the settings for `\@startsection` does (`\section` etc is defined in terms of this macro)

Answer (score 1):

For a start you can use the `layouts` package to draw diagrams and list values.

```
% layoutprob.tex  SE 572943
\documentclass[a4,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}
%\setuplayouts

Figure~\ref{fig:pplt} shows the parameters controling the page layout.

\begin{figure}
\pagediagram
\caption{Page layout parameters}\label{fig:pplt}
\end{figure}

Figure~\ref{fig:ptrs} shows the page layout parameter values for this document.

\begin{figure}
\setlayoutscale{0.45}
\currentpage
\pagedesign
\caption{Page layout values for this document} \label{fig:ptrs}
\end{figure}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `layouts` package can also be used to show the design parameters of paragraphs, lists, floats, etc.

As @daleif says, for font sizes read `size11.clo` and division headings `article.cls`, both of which will be on your system somewhere assuming that you have installed LaTeX and friends.