# Recovering default margin behaviour using `geometry`

Tags: margins, geometry

I am wondering, for a document from class `article` with the following setup:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
```

**What values should one input into fields `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` (in inches or points) from package `geometry` to recover the default margin behaviour from the document?**

```latex
\usepackage[top=¿?, bottom=¿?, left=¿?, right=¿?]{geometry}
```

I have found the following thread but it does not seem to answer my question: [Default margins for geometry package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44846/default-margins-for-geometry-package).

Auxiliary, how is can this default behaviour be checked? In particular, if I change the document type or the font size, the default behaviour might no longer be the same.

Comment: Did you try the approach from Werner's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44852/) (in the question you linked)? I think it'd help? `\usepackage{layouts} ... \begin{document} \pagevalues` prints text and paper width/height, margins, header/footer..., values which you can then input in `geometry`. Combine with `\usepackage{showframe}` for additional (visual) validation of the settings. Repeat after changing document type or font size.

Comment: @marquinho how can I establish a correspondence between the outputs of `\pagevalues` and the values for the parameters of `geometry`? Plus, I am not sure how to interpret the output, for example `\topmargin` has value `-37.0pt`, does that refer w.r.t. to the default value?

Answer (score 4):

Use the `layouts` package. For example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{layouts}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\currentpage
\oddpagelayouttrue
\pagedesign
\caption{Odd page layout for this document}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

will produce a diagram of the page layout and list the values of all the layout parameters.

The package provides many other facilities, such as drawing a proposed page layout.

Comment: `\oddpagelayout` is not recognized.

Comment: I tale liberty and correct command name  for `\oddpagelayout` to `\oddpagelayouttrue`

Answer (score 3):

The geometry package has a pass option which will prevent it from changing the paper size or margins set by the document class.

`\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`

Comment: Thank you, but I am specifically interested in knowing the values for the default behaviour to benchmark my current margins against the default ones.

Comment: Not sure this is exact, but 
`\usepackage[right=119pt,left=118pt,top=127pt,bottom=122pt]{geometry}` seems pretty darn close for 11pt oneside article class on a4paper.

Comment: Thank you, this works! But what are the default {geometry} settings which kick in when you leave the argument empty and you also don't have a paper size specified?

E.g.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[]{geometry} 

Are they set in pt, in, or some ratio, relative to something? What to put instead of [pass] to get the same exact result?

Need that to leave it as is for now but be able to change in the future.

Comment: Oh, I got it. This is what is [pass]ed: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573030/41937